# Представление данных в виде транзакций

Tags: r

Необходимо подготовить данные для работы с пакетом arules. Имеется data.frame, каждая строка содержит информацию о том, какую книгу пользователь добавил в корзину.

```r
            user_ip                    scenario basket_id added_book
1    128.23.167.174  /addbasket.phtml?id_book=8    ID4947          8
2   246.124.147.184 /addbasket.phtml?id_book=91    ID5114         91
3        58.5.54.48 /addbasket.phtml?id_book=56    ID5107         56
4   246.124.147.184 /addbasket.phtml?id_book=34    ID5114         34
5        58.5.54.48 /addbasket.phtml?id_book=63    ID5107         63
```

Я привел столбец user_ip к типу factor. Перебирая в цикле уровни (каждого пользователя), добавляю в list строку со списком книг, которые выбрал данный пользователь.

```r
buyers_actions$user_ip <- as.factor(buyers_actions$user_ip)
i <- 1
tvector <- vector(mode = "character", length = кол-во пользователей, оформивших заказ)
for (temp_lvl in levels(buyers_actions$user_ip)){
  temp <- subset(buyers_actions, user_ip == temp_lvl)$added_book
  tvector[i] <- list(subset(buyers_actions, user_ip == temp_lvl)$added_book)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Так как разные пользователи добавляют разное количество книг, то строки получаются разной длины. Из-за этого не получается воспользоваться функцией write.table(), а capture.output выводит криво.

Как переделать? Может вектор можно как-то по другому заполнять, чтобы на каждой строке был не список из строк, а одна объединенная строка?

Comment: да, действительно получилось сделать, если передавать не список строк, а объединенную строку (изначально у меня не получалось это сделать), т.е. ```tvector[i] <- paste( unlist(subset(buyers_actions, user_ip == temp_lvl)$added_book), collapse=",")```. Тогда ```write.table``` работает. Но раз уж я спросил, то может еще как-то лучше сделать можно? Например, без цикла обойтись.

Comment: и при чём тут транзакции? дайте, пожалуйста, вопросу более очевидный заголовок.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну, мне нужно было подготовить данные для работы с пакетом arules. для работы этому пакету необходим набор данных, в которых будет выполняться поиск ассоциативных правил. поиск ассоциативных правил выполняется в наборе транзакций. вот я этот набор транзакций и пытался подготовить. в этом случае одна транзакция - это книги, которые купил конкретный пользователь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если ограничиться только базовыми пакетами, то для объединения в группы можно воспользоваться, например, [функцией `aggregate()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/topics/aggregate), а внутри неё вызвать [функцию `paste()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/paste) для конкатенации сгруппированных значений в строку (именно этой функции и предназначен параметр `collapse`):

```r
d <- data.frame(ip = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 3), book = 1:6)
d
#>   ip book
#> 1  a    1
#> 2  a    2
#> 3  a    3
#> 4  b    4
#> 5  b    5
#> 6  b    6
aggregate(d$book, list(d$ip), paste, collapse = ' ')
#>   Group.1     x
#> 1       a 1 2 3
#> 2       b 4 5 6
```